# Node.js Express: passing parameters between client pages

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node.js server. Lets say each client has his name saved on a variable. They switch page and I want each client to mantain their name on a variable.

This would be very easy with a php form, but I can't see how to do it with Node.js
If I do a form like I would do in php, I manage to send the name to the server:

```
app.post('/game.html', function(req, res){
    var user = req.param('name');
    console.log(user);
    res.redirect('/game.html');
    });
```

But it seems too complicated to then resend it again to each client it's own.
I just started with Node.js, I guess it's a concept error. Is there any easy way to pass a variable from one page in the client to another?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you redirect at the end? And to the same url? You should simply render a template and pass `user` variable to it.

Comment: The website is made of static files. I got a variable in a page, I just need to pass it to the next one, using POST for example. It's easy with php, asp, jps... I would like to know how to do it with Node.js

Comment: You don't understand the concept. If PHP, ASP or whatever passes a variable to a file, then this file is no longer static, now is it? Or it is possible that you are talking about cookies/sessions ( are you? ), but that would be more complicated ( and it would require JavaScript in order to use that in static file ). So here's what you have to do: render the template ( instead of redirecting ) with an additional variable.

Comment: Thanks. With your advice I investigated further and I realized I need to use templates. I was trying to turn my .php files into .html ones, thinking Node would just feed my dynamic content in real time. But I still needed dynamic pages. I will use EJS, which looks better for beginners than jade.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of redirecting to a static file, you have to render the template ( using any engine that ExpressJS supports ):

```
app.post('/game.html', function(req, res){
    var user = req.param('name');
    console.log(user);
    res.render( 'game.html', { user:user } );
});
```

( note that `.render` requires some additonal settings set on `app` )

Now `user` variable becomes available in `game.html` template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use res.render and pass many variables, like that:

```
res.render('yourPage', {username:username, age:age, phone:phone});
```

Comment: yes, but this cannot be handled by a route handler, it just renders the page.